# Styling uneditable-input checkbox and textbox

Tags: css, checkbox, textbox, html-table

I'm making a login form within a table but I'm having a hard time formatting everything just the way I want to (never mind the left margin of the table, is just messed up on paint).

I want to make it look something like this:

[image: how it should look]

However it currently looks like this:

[image: wrong]

The whole table is inside a div called "span54".

The checkbox "box" currently has 50px width (I want it like that), however this also affects the width of the textboxes.

How can I differentiate textboxes within that div?

The current CSS code:

checkbox (inspected checkox)

[image]

textbox (inspected textbox)

[image]

table code

```
<table class="logintable">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" rowspan="1">Login</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="creds"><asp:label id="user" runat="server" text="User:" /></td>
                    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><input id="UserNameTextBox" type="text" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vUserName" ControlToValidate="UserNameTextBox" Display="Static" ErrorMessage="Username Inválido" runat="server" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="creds"><asp:label id="pass" runat="server" text="Password:" /></td>
                    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><input id="PasswordTextBox" type="password" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vUserPass" ControlToValidate="PasswordTextBox" Display="Static" ErrorMessage="Password Inválida" runat="server" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" rowspan="1"><asp:Button ID="btnlogin" runat="server" Text="Login" Class="btn-login" onclick="LoginButton_Click" /><asp:CheckBox id="RemPassword" cssclass="checkbox" runat="server" autopostback="false" text="Lembrar-me"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><asp:Label id="MsgLabel" runat="server" /></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit file dq.css, near line 336 change `width:50px;` to `width:160px;`

Comment: i already tried that but if i mess with line 336 it messes up the textbox alignment on other pages.

i tried to force the textboxes and checkbox to inherit from the following code but to no avail

input.span54,
textarea.span54,
.uneditable-input.span54 {
width: 120px;
margin-left: 15px;
}

am i doing something wrong?